# How does Linux Kernel treat hidden files?

Tags: linux, shell, file, hidden-files

*"Hidden files"* are files with name prefix `.`, e.g. `/home/pxf/.xxx`.
`.xxx` is an invisible file and 'ls' will not list it.

Is there a concept of *"hidden file"* On Linux Kernel? I mean that are there difference between *"regular files"* and *"hidden files"*?

Or just it's a conventional rule that a file with prefix `.` will not be shown by default such as `ls`. (except with `-a` option)?

Comment: No, there is nothing special about it. It is just basically a "hint" for software to not show it unless the user requests for it, but it makes no difference. So the last sentence in your question is correct.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Unix & Linux Stack Exchange](http://unix.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306)

Comment: Historically, it started out as a bug in `ls` which was never fixed because people started using it as a feature. Instead `ls` gained the `-a` flag

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See Wikipedia: [Hidden file and hidden directory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hidden_file_and_hidden_directory)

> They are not a security mechanism because access is not restricted - usually the intent is simply not "clutter" the display of the contents of a directory listing with files the user did not directly create.

This is just a convenient convention that application may or may not observe. The invisibility of these files is not enforced by the kernel.

Comment: So is the Environment Variable 'PATH' just a **convention** for shell searching executable files too?

Comment: @TanakaYasen: Yes, specifically there are shells (or shell-like programs) where the path variable is a different name. It's also what causes a lot of surprise to people using things like `cron` because some software execute the command string directly without invoking a subshell (that's possible because C has an execve function)

Comment: @slebetman `cron` does not execute the command directly. It invokes a shell which executes the command. What is generally unexpected with `cron` is that `PATH` is not read from the user's rc files; it is set to a minimal value instead. As for the C functions, there are `execlp`, `execvp` and `execvpe` which do search the executable in the `PATH` environment variable. Those are not system calls (kernel functions) though.

Comment: @slebetman `PATH` is not just a convention. It's [part of the POSIX standard](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html#tag_08): *This variable shall represent the sequence of path prefixes that certain functions and utilities apply in searching for an executable file known only by a filename...* It's [effect on the `exec` family of functions is specified](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/exec.html):  *the path prefix for this file is obtained by a search of the directories passed as the environment variable `PATH`*

Comment: @AndrewHenle Yes, but the POSIX standard is just a convention as well. As I said, there are shells where the executable path is not managed by a variable called PATH. tcl is one example. Before you say that's a language, not a shell note that bash is a language as well. And there is (or used to be) a distro of linux that uses tclsh as the default shell (the only shell installed in fact, that distro does not even use init, it replaced the init process with a tcl script)